# Need help in limiting ibkr api send to 50msg/min

Tags: python, error-handling, interactive-brokers

How can I limit send to 50 msg/min for my requests? I am trying to get data for all SnP500 symbols but the following code keeps getting same error.

```
   
    def sendreq(self):
        count = 0
        
        self.reqContractDetails(1010, contract)
        count += 1

        if count > 30:
            print(send)
            print('sleeping')
            # print(contract)
            time.sleep(1)
            count = 0
```

Received the following error:

Error:  9   100   Max rate of messages per second has been exceeded:max=50 rec=61 (1)

Comment: You should edit the question and add more information about the error you have. For example paste the relevant part of the error traceback.

Comment: Thanks added the error from the IBKR API

Comment: Your edits aren't fixing anything and you don't need to fix the code here anyway.  You still set count = 0 then check if count > 30.  That will obviously never happen.

Answer (score 0):

You set `send=0` every call and check if it's > 30.

You are using the same reqId every time, how will you differentiate the responses?

Probably a typo in the question but it's 50/sec limit (actually a 250/5sec average)

I don't think that's how globals work in python, instead it should be declared in the class and use `self.send`.